# Remove a connection from server

Tags: linux, rhel

Someone i dont want to be connected is connected to my server. Is it possible to kill the connection between my server and this person, all i know is there ip.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tcpkill` command:

```
tcpkill host <IP address>
```

And then block the IP address in your firewall.